# SELECT Last Row Hackerrank challenger for SSMS without using TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Here's the following question on hackerrank.com:

........................

Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

Input Format

The STATION table is described as follows:

field - type: id - number, city - varchar(21), state - varchar(2), lat_n - number, long_w - number

where LAT_N is the northern latitude and LONG_W is the western longitude.

Sample Input

Let's say that CITY only has four entries: DEF, ABC, PQRS and WXY

Sample Output

ABC 3
PQRS 4
Explanation

When ordered alphabetically, the CITY names are listed as ABC, DEF, PQRS, and WXY, with the respective lengths  and . The longest-named city is obviously PQRS, but there are  options for shortest-named city; we choose ABC, because it comes first alphabetically.

Note
You can write two separate queries to get the desired output. It need not be a single query.

.................................................

I wanted to solve it with 1 query, so I used a CTE:

```
    with cte as(
                SELECT  City,
                        LEN (City)     as l,
                        MAX (LEN (City)) over() as x,
                        MIN (LEN (City)) OVER() as m,
 --                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(city),city) AS r
                FROM    Station

                )
    SELECT  city,
            l
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   l = x  OR l = m
    --WHERE   l = x  OR r = 1
    ORDER BY L, city;
```

but it gives the error:

Your Output (stdout)

Amo 3

Lee 3

Roy 3

Marine On Saint Croix 21

because there are only meant to be 2 cities, one with a Length of 3 and the other with a length of 21.  So I changed the code as such: (note the changes in Rem'd out code)

```
    with cte as(
                SELECT  City,
                        LEN (City)     as l,
                        MAX (LEN (City)) over() as x,
--                        MIN (LEN (City)) OVER() as m,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(city),city) AS r
                FROM    Station

                )
    SELECT  city,
            l
    FROM    cte
--    WHERE   l = x  OR l = m
    WHERE   l = x  OR r = 1
    ORDER BY L, city;
```

This is right, gives the output as:
Your Output (stdout)

Amo 3

Marine On Saint Croix 21

Changing the code solved the duplicate length 3 problem as I knew the first row number.  But my problems arose if I tried to obtain the last row number without knowing what the number was.  Every other post I have seen for finding the last row on SSMS involves using TOP but as you can see TOP will only retrieve one row but I need 2 for my answer as I am trying to solve a 2 query question in 1 query.

Basically, I solved the query but I'd like to know how you could do this if there were 2 cities that had a length of 21.  How would I find the last row in this situation?

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem like you are there -- understanding how `row_number()` works.  You just need to use it twice.  The logic you want is:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT City,LEN (City) as l,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LEN(city), city) AS seqnum_min,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LEN(city) DESC, city) AS seqnum_max
      FROM Station
     )
SELECT city, l
FROM cte
WHERE 1 IN (seqnum_min, seqnum_max)
ORDER BY L, city;
```

Using `TOP`, you would probably use `UNION ALL`:

```
select *
from ((select top (1) s.*
       from station s
       order by len(city), city
      ) union all
      (select top (1) s.*
       from station s
       order by len(city) desc, city
      ) 
     ) s
```

Comment: The first one works a charm, very tidy... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The cte approach could also work, selecting min(city) group by len(city):

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT  
    LEN(City) AS l,
    MIN(City) AS city,
    MAX(LEN (City)) OVER() AS maxlen,
    MIN(LEN (City)) OVER() AS minlen
FROM  (VALUES('abc'), ('klm'), ('xyz'), ('bcde'), ('cdef'), ('bcdef'), ('cdefg'), ('pqrstu'), ('aqrstu')) AS Station(City) --Station
GROUP BY LEN(City)
)
SELECT  city,
        l
FROM    cte
WHERE   l = maxlen  OR l = minlen
ORDER BY l, city;
```